# R - outliers with complex data

Tags: r, modeling, outliers

By now I'm convinced of the importance and improvement gained when using the robust packages (ex: baserobust) to fit data. I've use it both for linear and non-linear fitting with some degree of sucess. However, I don't know how to analyse my new dataset.

Here I have a model that, based on a couple of parameters, predict the dynamics of 3 different quantities. For each quantity we have several replicate measures. In some cases it is obvious that some of the replicates are outliers (very different behaviour) or that some points only are outliers. Given the large dataset size, I can not identify them all manually. What do you sugest?

Comment: Isn't that one of the things robust fitting procedures provide automatically: identification of outliers?  And given that--by definition--these procedures are supposed to be resistant to the effects of outliers, could you explain the objective of identifying the outliers?

Comment: The problem is that, as far as I understood, the R packages are design to fit one type of data. Here I have 3 different types of data.